# Do you need to use the `-I` flag in `gcc` if the program has the `#include` statements?

Tags: c, gcc, include

In my `C` my program, I included the header files I need with a `#include` statement.

When compiling [on a Linux server] do I need to an `-I/` flag in the `gcc` command as well?

I noticed in some places it's included, but in some others its not. I'd really appreciate a definitive answer.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard set of `include` directories.  For gcc, you check the preprocessor:

```
 cpp -v < /dev/null
```

Which outputs:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

These generally cover the standard headers and such.  For your own headers, especially in a folder hierarchy, you may need additional `-I` flags.

Comment: I don't understand... what does this tell me?

Comment: It says: if you `#include` something, it will look there without having to specify `-I`.  If your include files are elsewhere you may need to use `-I` for those paths.

Comment: So including something in quotations does nothing basically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Answer (score 0):

In short, `-I` tells the compiler where to look for the headers.

Some paths are already searched by the compiler, such as `/usr/include`. For those headers, you don't `-I` (e.g. the standard headers or installed libraries). For headers in a location unknown to the compiler, such as your own program or a library whose source you have downloaded, you need to specify the include path (via `-I`) otherwise the compiler has no idea where to find the include file.

Note that when you include with `"file"` instead of `<file>`, the compiler first searches the directory where the including file itself is. For example, let's say you have a directory structure like this:

```
project
|
+- include
|  |
|  +- header1.h
|  |
|  `- header2.h
|
`- src
   |
   +- funcs1.c
   |
   +- funcs2.c
   |
   `- internal.h
```

Now let's see some examples:

```
funcs1.c:

#include "internal.h"
```

Compiling this doesn't need `-I` because `internal.h` is in the same location as `funcs1.c`.

```
funcs1.c:

#include <internal.h>
```

This needs `-I/path/to/project/src` (or `-I.` if you are calling the compiler in the same directory as `funcs1.c`) because `#include <...>` doesn't search in the directory of the source file.

```
funcs2.c:

#include <header1.h>
/* or */
#include "header1.h"
```

This needs `-I/path/to/project/include` (or `-I../include` if you are calling the compiler in the same direcotry as `funcs2.c`) because the location of `header1.h` is unknown to the compiler in either case. Note that this is regardless of where you call the compiler since the compiler doesn't look at the directory it is being called from, but in the directory the source file is.

```
funcs1.c:

#include "internal.h"

internal.h:

#include "header2.h"
```

This still needs `-I/path/to/project/include` because even though `internal.h` is found to be included in `funcs1.c`, it tries to include `header2.h` whose path needs to be told to the compiler.